# How can I get values from one column copied to another sheet only if a value exists in a second column

Tags: excel, vba

New here, and trying to find a solution to auto create work orders and materials lists from a list of upgrades.  I think I may need to write a VBA for this.
Below is a table like what we have in one of our sheets.  We need to be able to copy the values in column a (CFM target reduction, Recessed light box, etc) in to another spreadsheet only if the value in column c is greater than 0.

```
+--------------------------------------+--+----+------+
|          Fire Rated Sealing          |  |    |  LF  |
+--------------------------------------+--+----+------+
| CFM Target Reduction                 |  |  1 | CFM  |
| Recessed Light Box                   |  | 10 | EA   |
| Seal Ducts at Plenum                 |  |  1 | Duct |
| Attic Access Mate- Magnetic          |  |  1 | EA   |
| Attic Tent for Attic Stairs (zipper) |  |  0 | EA   |
| Attic Insulation- Blown in Cellulose |  |  0 | SF   |
| Batt Insulation- Fiberglass          |  |  0 | SF   |
| Insulate Condensent Line             |  |  0 | LF   |
| Knee wall:  (Insul. w/ Fiberglass)   |  |  2 | SF   |
| Knee wall:  (Seal w/ Foamboard)      |  |  4 | SF   |
+--------------------------------------+--+----+------+
```

I tried this with IF functions, however it ended up with just this -

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║                 0                  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════╣
║ CFM Target Reduction               ║
║ Recessed Light Box                 ║
║ Seal Ducts at Plenum               ║
║ Attic Access Mate- Magnetic        ║
║ 0                                  ║
║ 0                                  ║
║ 0                                  ║
║ 0                                  ║
║ Knee wall:  (Insul. w/ Fiberglass) ║
║ Knee wall:  (Seal w/ Foamboard)    ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Which is unattractive and doesn't fit our needs.  What we need is to return *only* the values of column A to another spreadsheet without the zeroes.  Ideally we'd also be able to query a short description of each of the items on the work order.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have a formula which doesn't do what you need, then try including it in your question.

Comment: Columns in this formula don't correspond to the example above, but here's the formula - =IF(E53>0,C53,)

As for going 'as is' that is an option, however we'd prefer a solution that does this automatically. We do this about 40 times a day with several different individuals, so an automated solution that is locked to prevent editing is the ideal solution.  Allowing editing would allow the people receiving the work order to possibly game the system.

Comment: Have you looked at vlookup?

Comment: @AlanWaage I don't see how Vlookup helps in this case, since it would still leave gaps on values that were not selected.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple macro:

```
Sub test()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet
   Dim sh2 As Worksheet
   Dim lastrow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   'you can change Sheet1 and Sheet2 to your sheet names'
   Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

   'determining last row in Sheet1 in column A (I suppose that your data in column A)'
   lastrow = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'I suppose that in Sheet2 your data will starts from row №2'
   j = 2 

   'I suppose that in Sheet1 your data will starts from row №2 too'
   For i = 2 To lastrow
       'if in Sheet1 in column C there is value greater 0, than copy'
       If sh1.Range("C" & i) > 0 Then
           'copy data from sheet1 column A to sheet2 column A'
           sh2.Range("A" & j) = sh1.Range("A" & i)
           j = j + 1
       End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Dan, in what line have you got an error? Maybe you need to change names `"Sheet1"` and `"Sheet2"` to SheetNames that are true for you?

Comment: @Dan, in what column your values 1,10,1,1,0,... I suppose that they are in column `C`. Is it true?

Comment: I was about to write you a detailed explanation of the error, but after using the new code update, it works!  It doesn't carry over the value in column C, however, but this is a great start!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the relevant cells of data including the headings (A1:C12?)
2. Insert > Pivot table
3. Drag "Fire Rated Sealing" to the ROWS section
   of the pivot table
4. Drag "Heading of Column C" to the VALUES section
   of the pivot table
5. Click the filter icon for "Fire Rated Sealing"
   and choose Value Filters > Greater Than 0.

Comment: Excel won't allow us to create a Pivot Table because we have merged cells in this part of the spreadsheet.